# Change text value through a static text reference?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am searching through my DisplayContainer for text fields to change them but i have a problem with changing the reference:

```
    for (var i:uint = 0, n:uint = rootContainer.numChildren; i < n; ++i) {
        var item:DisplayObject = rootContainer.getChildAt(i);
        if (item is DisplayObjectContainer) {
            updateFields(DisplayObjectContainer(item));
        } else if (item is TextField) {
            item.text  = "hej";
        }
    }
```

The item.text throws:

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property text through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

How do i convert it so i can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type it as a `TextField` before you can call a `TextField` method on it:

```
for (var i:uint = 0, n:uint = rootContainer.numChildren; i < n; ++i) {
    var item:DisplayObject = rootContainer.getChildAt(i);
    if (item is DisplayObjectContainer) {
        updateFields(DisplayObjectContainer(item));
    } else if (item is TextField) {
        var textField:TextField = item as TextField;
        textField.text  = "hej";
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks! Always thought about how you use a static reference and this explains it to me. I was thinking about of doing like:
 var objecto:* = rootContainer.getChildAt(i);
 objecto.text  = "hej";
But this solves it! THANK YOU!

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Make sure to mark the question as answered so in the future people can see the marked solution if they have the same question.

Comment: Yes i marked you! Couldn't mark you within the first 15 minutes so just waited for it. Haven't forgot you. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, indeed. Forgot I was a speedy hand with that answer ;) Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!